# Understanding MySQL Integer Types?

Tags: mysql

Please could someone explain to me how the MySQL integer types and lengths work as it is somewhat confusing.

Which different integer types and lengths should I use for each of the following ranges to keep them as efficient as possible?

```
0 - 1
0 - 700,000
0 - 9,999,999,999
```

What is the difference between TINYINT(5), SMALLINT(5) and INT(5), are they the same?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Do you think I didn't look at that first? Does that answer my question? No.

Comment: I don't understand if you go through this link then why you asked that question ? In a single answer to your question your comment changed your question completely ...For this question Understanding MySQL Integer Types?  only that link can be useful resource available.

Comment: If I choose BOOLEAN it defaults to TINYINT(1) but only allows 0 or 1, which is not the same as 0-255. And then all the integer sizes allow for a length... so obviously it is not as simple as that table on the MySQL site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `0-1`, a bit is perfect.

For `0 - 7,00,000` you can have `UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT`

and for the last one `UNSIGNED INT` will work.

---

Refer [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for information about the ranges they provide.

```
Type    Storage Minimum Value   Maximum Value
    (Bytes) (Signed/Unsigned)   Signed/Unsigned)
TINYINT 1   -128    127
        0   255
SMALLINT    2   -32768  32767
        0   65535
MEDIUMINT   3   -8388608    8388607
        0   16777215
INT 4   -2147483648 2147483647
        0   4294967295
BIGINT  8   -9223372036854775808    9223372036854775807
        0   18446744073709551615
```

---

There is no difference if you use `INT(5)` or `INT(10)` or even `INT(1)`. The number in parenthesis is just width to display when fetching results.

---

[This link](http://matthom.com/archive/2006/11/28/mysql-integer-columns-and-display-width) will help you further.

Comment: Yes, yes I know that. But what is the difference between MEDIUMINT(5) and TINYINT(5), as both have 5 specified as length?

Comment: @Alasdair Check the edit. Also, MEDIUMINT and TINYINT with any number in parenthesis will still have the same ranges as in the link above. Just their default display width will be set to 5.